# What method of extracting oil from almonds preserves the most almond flavor?

Tags: almonds, extracts

Which would be the best way to extract oil from Almonds preserving the strongest flavour of Almonds?

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. Flavor is on-topic here, so I'll reopen.

Comment: Preserves most flavour in the almond flour or in the oil?

Comment: oil is mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own extract easily using vodka/neutral spirits and crushed almonds, filling a glass jar with half vodka/neutral spirits and half crushed almonds, letting it sit for a month or so to extract the flavor and oils, you can make a vanilla extract in the same way.

Comment: What happens to the alcohol?

Comment: you only use a teaspoon or so in most recipes, and the alcohol amount is then negligible and/or likely evaporates.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question: 
Almond extract that you buy from the store is made from bitter almonds, while almonds you buy from the store are generally sweet almonds because raw bitter almonds contain cyanide. Do not expect almond extract that you make from sweet almonds to be the same as the store bought extract from bitter almonds.

Answer (score 0):

Generaly speaking, only once cold pressed  oils not too finely filtered (a bit cloudy) are best for flavor and worse for keeping and high heat cooking (frying) .

On the opposite, heated, heat pressed and heavily filtered (with help from some chemicals) oils can be kept an eternity, support their highest possible cooking temperature but have the less flavor.

Comment: I'd agree with the cold pressed oil. Stating that (heated) oils keep 'an eternity' is odd. Could you provide a link?

Comment: About the [first press](http://www.oliveoilsource.com/article/first-cold-press-obsolete-term-it%E2%80%99s-fact)